# dynamic programming, coin change, memory leak?

Tags: c++, c, qt, coin-change

I writing program to change coin. When i write printf in loops to print i or j program give good results, when I delete it, program stops. I think it's problem with memory but I'm writing on Windows in QT and i have no access to valgrind.

Anyone can check this? First give numbers of denomination, second - denominations, last is amount.

E.g:

```
3
1 3 5
8
```

result should be 2.

```
1
5
3
```

result sholud be NO.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INF 2147483647 //nieskonczonosc


void nominal(int nominaly, int T[], int k)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=nominaly; i++ )          
       {
         int n=0;
         scanf("%d", &n);           
         int j;                     
         for ( j=0;j<=k-n;++j) {  
           if (T[j] < INF)                       
             if (T[j]+1 < T[j+n])   
               T[j+n] = T[j]+1;

       }
    }

    int kwota=0;
    scanf("%d", &kwota);
    if(T[kwota]==INF){
        printf("NO");
    }else
    printf("%d", T[kwota]);

}

int main() {

    int n=0;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int k=10000;
    int *T;
    T = (int*)malloc(k * sizeof(int));
    T[0]=0;
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=k;++i)
        {                   
         T[i]=INF;
         }
    nominal(n, T, k);

    free(T);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Pardon me, but how is this code in any way related to Qt? Perhaps, it would be better to remove the qt tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input is well-formed, the only problem I can spot in your code is in these lines:

```
if (T[j]+1 < T[j+n])   
    T[j+n] = T[j]+1;
```

When `j` reaches the value `k-n`, `T[j+n]` is an out-of-bounds access, because you get `k-n+n`, so you are accessing `T[k]`, and the last valid position is `T[k-1]`. This invokes undefined behavior in your program - anything (including working as expected) can happen.

You might want to rewrite that `for` loop to something like:

```
for (j=0; j < k-n;++j) { ... }
```

There are no memory leaks in your code.

Comment: thanks for help, in `malloc` a change `k*sizeof(int)` for `(k+1)*sizeof(int)` and it work good :)